# Add reference lines at specific degree/minute/seconds?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, latitude-longitude

I need to add reference lines at specific latitudes, like the image here: https://nrm.dfg.ca.gov/FileHandler.ashx?DocumentID=113031&inline

Here's what I've tried/found so far:

- I found ESRI's base layer lat/long grid, but the resolution is not fine enough (it only goes to 1 degree)
- I found another group of files hosted by USGS (I believe) that had the resolution I need, but not the extent (I need it to cover California but also into the Pacific Ocean)
- I saw something about a "Reference Latitude" tool, but I don't appear to have the proper license to use it
- Lastly, I saw references in a couple of semi-similar questions to the "Create Fishnet" tool, but I honestly can't figure out what parameters to use to get what I need. I'm using the California Teale Albers (meters) projection.

This seems like something that would be really simple, but I can't figure it out.

I'm using ArcMap 10.8.1

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I should have mentioned that I tried that but I don't think it is what I'm looking for, particularly because the grid is only visible in layout view.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer to this question on an Esri forum. All I had to do was:

1. Create an excel table with coordinates along the lines of latitude that I wanted.
2. Display the XY data in ArcMap
3. Use the **Points to Line** tool.